# Edit Sold Listings Ebay Scrape VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

Looking for a way to do this one of two ways via excel VBA.

1) either to run a search on ebay for a part number and return the number of sold listings, or;

2) to perform the same task using a direct link.

Any ideas?

I have tried:

Public Sub GetNumberSold()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument

```
Set html = New HTMLDocument

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "https://www.ebay.com/itm/VIRGINIA-CAVALIERS-FINAL-FOUR-National-FREAKIN-Champions-T-Shirt-Gildan/352639122861", False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

MsgBox html.querySelector(".vi-txt-underline").innerText
Debug.Print Replace$(html.querySelector(".vi-txt-underline").innerText," sold",vbNullString)
Debug.Print split(html.querySelector(".vi-txt-underline").innerText,chr$(32))(0)

End Sub
```

With enabling both objects/references as requested below.

Then I get the following error:
run time"91" object variable or with block variable not set.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What research have you performed? Where did you get stuck? There are lots of ebay questions on StackOverflow to help you get started and we can help you when you have a specific problem. There is great guidance available at [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: Researched and tried various vba's for this, and I haven't been able to get one to work.

Comment: you should update via [edit] with the best of what you have tried and explain what should of happened and what did happen. Include any error messages and where the occur.

Comment: I have edited the first post to show what I have tried so far.

Comment: You need to add the relevant libraries via VBE (Alt + F11) > Tools > References then add reference for Microsoft HTML Object Library and Microsoft XML 6.0 (or appropriate version for you). That will get rid of first two errors.

Comment: Ok thanks, I've done that and added new message to first post.

Comment: Have you inspected the response text to ensure that class exists in the response? You can write the html to a text file then inspect in any tool that allows you to paste in html and apply css selectors e.g. jsoup Alternatively, with jsoup you can make the request direct through the tool and inspect the result in the GUI.